# WPF Binding to member of a class within a class

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

My first try at C#, WPF, and MVVM.  I've looked at several answers and tutorials and just cannot seem to get this right.

I have a View a Model and a ViewModel file (Actually more, but trying to simplify). In the view I want to bind a textbox to a view model member.  I also want to bind a button click to a view model method.

The delegate command for `Login(`) works fine, but I can't seem to update the ID property in `Acc.ID`. 
What would I need to change to be able to do both?

I understand I will probably need to implement the `PropertyChanged` event in the ViewModel instead of the Model...I just don't understand how.

What I can do is set the `DataContext`to `user.Acc` in the code behind to directly update the model, but then I obviously cannot bind to the `Login()` method.

ViewModel.cs

```
public class LoginVM
{
    private ServerInterface _serverInterface;

    private ICommand _loginCommand;

    private EmployeeAccount _acc;

    public ICommand LoginCommand
    {
        get { return _loginCommand; }
    }

    public LoginVM()
    {
        Acc = new EmployeeAccount();

        _serverInterface = new ServerInterface();

        _loginCommand = new DelegateCommand<String>(Login);
    }

    public EmployeeAccount Acc { get; set; }

    private void Login(object state)
    {

        this.Acc.ID = _serverInterface.Encrypt(this.Acc.ID);

    }
}
```

View.xaml.cs

```
 public partial class LoginView : Window
{
    public LoginView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        BindInXaml();
    }

    private void BindInXaml()
    {
        base.DataContext = new LoginVM();
    }
}
```

Model.cs

```
public class EmployeeAccount : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    String _id;


    public EmployeeAccount()
    {
        ID = "5000";
        Name = "George Washington";
        isAdmin = true;
        Pswd = "TheyDont";
    }

    public String ID
    {
        get { return _id; }
        set
        {
            _id = value;
        this.OnPropertyChanged("ID");
        }
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Boolean isAdmin { get; set; }

    public string Pswd { get; set; }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;


    void OnPropertyChanged(string propName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
            this.PropertyChanged(
                this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
    }

}
```

.xaml **Put in only what matters really**

```
<TextBox x:Name="txtLogInName" Margin="60,43,42,129" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Path=ID, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="120" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"/>
        <Button x:Name="btnLogIn" Content="Log on" Command="{Binding LoginCommand}" Margin="160,151,10,23" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" RenderTransformOrigin="1.667,0.545"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="txtBlockPassReset" TextAlignment="Center"  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" RenderTransformOrigin="1.348,1.765" Margin="60,101,42,78">
          <Hyperlink>Reset Password</Hyperlink>
        </TextBlock>
        <PasswordBox x:Name="pswdBoxLoginPass" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="60,72,0,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Password="Password"/>
```

Comment: There is no issue in your code. The Login method should update the ID value. Please post your XAML binding code also to investigate further.

Comment: the binding to the ID is {Binding Acc.ID} ? or show your xaml

Comment: I posted it for you.  The Acc.ID does not get updated at all...I assume this is because the PropertyChanged event is one level too deep.  If I bind DataContext to user.Acc, then the property updates but leaves no way for the method to be bound in LoginVM.cs

Comment: Try changing it to `<TextBox x:Name="txtLogInName" Margin="60,43,42,129" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Path=Acc.ID, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="120" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"/>`

Comment: Ya...holy crap that did it. I wasn't aware that was proper syntax usage in xaml.  I also thought that the OnPropertyChanged() argument had to be the same as the binding path.  Anyways, thanks...throw in the answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing your xaml from

```
<TextBox x:Name="txtLogInName" Margin="60,43,42,129" TextWrapping="Wrap" 
    Text="{Binding Path=ID, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
    Width="120" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"/>
```

to

```
<TextBox x:Name="txtLogInName" Margin="60,43,42,129" TextWrapping="Wrap" 
    Text="{Binding Path=Acc.ID, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
    Width="120" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" />
```